# simple object-oriented JavaScript example

Tags: javascript

I'm learning OO JavaScript (again). I've written this simple object

```
function circle(){
  this.radius = 4;
}

circle.prototype.area = function(){
  this.radius * this.radius * 3.14;
};

var c = new circle();
c.area();
```

The value returned by `c.area()` is `undefined`. I guess this can only because `this.radius` is not returning 4, why not?

Comment: Use `Math.PI` instead of 3.14.

Comment: By convention, constructors start with a capital letter. By default they return the newly constructed object so you don't need a return statement. **But** methods must have a return statement if you want them to return a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`radius` has the value of `4`, but the `area` method doesn't **return** any value.

```
circle.prototype.area = function(){
  return this.radius * this.radius * 3.14;
};
```

Comment: I would add: `if (typeof this.area != 'number') this.area = Math.pow(this.radius, 2)*Math.PI; return this.area;`.

Comment: @RobG I wouldn't. In fact, you'd override the `area()` method with the `area` member => `area` will be callable at the beginning but won't after the first call.

Comment: @duri thanks, I've been using Groovy for too long (where the return statement is optional)

Comment: @duri - doh, of course! Anyhow, just an exercise for the OP I suspect.